# How to Clean Install on reformated disc?

Tags: system-installation

How do I install Ubuntu on a freshly re-formatted hard-drive?  The machine has a CD player but the Ubuntu ISO is on a DVD that the player won't read.  The ISO is about 50MB too large for a CD.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can install ubuntu from USB Stick.
If you have another computer with windows or ubuntu you can follow this instructions:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

or

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks.  But, that's where I'm stuck.  The CD won't read a DVD and the iso is too big to put on a CDR. So, I can only boot from a dos floppy or a system that fits on the CDR.  I installed Slax (a small linux system) but can't connect to net with it...

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try this  older 'minimal' route if it still works, then upgrade over the net.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

another thought is to use an external DVD drive - about $29 at Amazon.com.